# Is it possible to have Ember show a query parameter value in the url when the parameter is set to the default value?

Tags: ember.js

According to [the docs](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/query-params/#toc_default-values-and-deserialization), "When a controller's query param property is currently set to its default value, this value won't be serialized into the URL."

[Here is a jsbin](http://jsbin.com/ucanam/6517/edit) showing this behavior.

Is it possible to "disable" this behavior and always have the query params show in the URL regardless of their value?

Reason: I am dynamically setting the default value for a timestamp query parameter. However, I want the URLs to be shareable, so I want to explicitly list the timestamp in the URL. I'm also using the query parameters default value (which I set to the current time) for knowing whether to show a "clear timestamp" button.

Comment: Not Ember expert, but I'd guess it would make sense not to have a default value (or equivalently, for the default value to be blank); if no param is provided, redirect to current time. This would make it impossible not to have time in the URL, making it always shareable, while still allowing users to access the URL without the time parameter.

Comment: Because I don't have a full answer, I'll just make a comment. But I found the [serializeQueryParam](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/v1.7.0/packages/ember-routing/lib/system/route.js#L1753) function in the `Route` class that you can override. I would try overriding that function and watch when it gets called and with what values. It seems like that would be where you would override the default value behavior.